# Python regex split before regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.4

Here is the problem:

string = 'abcdefghijklmn opabcedfg'

desired_result = ['abcdefghijklmn op', 'abcedfg']

I am looking for "abc" by regular expression: re.compile(r"abc")
and splitting thereafter on the basis of this regex.
This gives:
['abc','defghijklmn op','abc','dfg']

Can I adjust my regex to reach the desired split?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex similar to this one:

```
abc[^a]*(?:a(?!bc)[^a]*)*
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF8vR8/1)

It will collect all substrings starting with `abc` and up to the first `abc` met or the end of string.

Regex breakdown:

- `abc` - match `abc`
- `[^a]*` - match 0 or more characters other than `a`
- `(?:a(?!bc)[^a]*)*` - match (but not capture) 0 or more sequences of

  - `a(?!bc)` - match `a` that is not followed with `bc` (as we are matching up to `abc`)
  - `[^a]*` - match 0 or more characters other than `a`

It is similar to what [`abc.*?(?=$|abc)`](https://regex101.com/r/eF8vR8/2) would capture, but is free from the issues associated with lazy dot matching.

[Python code demo](http://ideone.com/anlj4H):

```
p = re.compile(r'abc[^a]*(?:a(?!bc)[^a]*)*')
test_str = "abcdefghijklmn opabcedfg"
print(p.findall(test_str))
```

Results: `['abcdefghijklmn op', 'abcedfg']`